# Where can I find Bourbaki's Latin telegram?

Tags: mathematics, bourbaki

In the Bourbaki archives in Lorainne, France, there appears to be a Latin telegram from Nicolas Bourbaki to Marcel Brelot (see reference 486 at https://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/files/2021/04/DELSARTE_archives_Bourbaki_cote_BKI.pdf).

Is this document publicly available? I have a particular interest in the history of Latin as a language of mathematics, and this seems to be one of the last uses of the language by a famous mathematician (group) - although it was most likely some kind of joke.

Comment: Have you tried e-mailing the library? In my experience librarians are only too pleased to answer queries like this.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, I'm waiting for their reply